# how to add picker in toolbar in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, toolbar, picker

i want to add picker for dropdownn options in tool bar..right now I have added labels like this

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Name="Approval V" />  
  <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="1" Name="sort"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

but I don't find any solution to put picker here..Please give me some suggestion..

Answer (score 5):

i found solution of it which i would like to share.if it can help others.

```
     <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Name="Approval Now" />
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Name="Tasks - Future" />
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Name="Meeting - Future" />
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="1" Name="sort"  Clicked="sort_click" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

in xaml.cs

```
 private async void sort_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string StorageFolder = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(SystemMessages.PhothotoSaveFolder, "Cancel", null, SystemMessages.InstallationPhothoto, SystemMessages.SerialNumbers);
        var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Sort Options", "Cancel", null, "By Approval Due Date", "Meeting Date", "Meeting Type");
        Debug.WriteLine("Action: " + action);

    }
```